Checkmark flagging an issue with Crosssite scripting
Checkmark is flagging a cross site scripting issue in JSP.
This is the issue checkmark displaying:

The method "javascript:getdata() embeds untrusted data in generated output with BinaryExpr, at line 114 of \main.jsp.  This untrusted data is embedded into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the generated web-page.

The code is below:
Code in JSP:
<a href="javascript:getData('${sta.Date}','${sta.EndDate}');">
  <fmt:formatDate value="${sta.EndDate}" pattern="MMM - yy " />
  <c:out value="${caa.selected.number} - ${caa.selected.number} " />
  <c:if test="${not empty sta.statement and  sta.statement!='' and sta.statement != ' '}">
    <c:out value=" - ${sta.statement}" />
  </c:if>
</a>

Code in Javascript file:
function getData(date, endDate) {
  var element1 = document.getElementsByName("selectedDate")[0];
  element1.value = date;
  var element2 = document.getElementsByName("selectedEndDate")[0];
  element2.value = endDate;
  formSubmit("showReport"); 
}

I want help in sanitizing the input so that check mark issue is resolved. The solutions in stackoverflow didn't solve my issue. can some one guide me what is wrong in the code that i posted and how to resolve the issue

Can some one point me what is the problem in the code

The code itself doesn't represent a problem. The problem is that you cannot use EL expressions in JavaScript without sanitizing.

Just replace ${sta.Date} by ${fn:escapeXml(sta.Date)} as instructed in abovelinked duplicate. Do the same for ${sta.EndDate} and all other expressions which can potentially contain user-controlled data.
